# Redirect stdout pipe of child process in Go

Tags: go, stdout, command-line-interface

I'm writing a program in Go that executes a server like program (also Go). Now I want to have the stdout of the child program in my terminal window where I started the parent program. One way to do this is with the `cmd.Output()` function, but this prints the stdout only after the process has exited. (That's a problem because this server-like program runs for a long time and I want to read the log output)

The variable `out` is of `type io.ReadCloser` and I don't know what I should do with it to achieve my task, and I can't find anything helpful on the web on this topic.

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/path/to/my/child/program")
    out, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    //fmt.Println(out)
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

Explanation to the code: uncomment the `Println` function to get the code to compile, I know that `Println(out io.ReadCloser)` is not a meaningful function.
 (it produces the output `&{3 |0 <nil> 0}` ) These two lines are just required to get the code to compile.

Comment: Your "exec" line of the import statement should be "os/exec".

Comment: thanks for the info, actually it was only exec pre go1, now its in os. updated it for go1

Comment: I don't think that you actually need to call `io.Copy` within go routines

Comment: I don't think you need to call `cmd.Wait()` or the `for{}` loop... why are these here?

Comment: @weberc2 for this look down to elimisteve's answer. The for loop is not needed if you just want to run the program once. But if you don't call cmd.Wait(), your main() may end before your called program finishes, and you don't get the output you want

Comment: @mbert I don't think that's true. Consider this example in which "helper" is a program w/ a loop that prints a number every second. `io.Copy()` will block until the program finishes. http://play.golang.org/p/_I1MxATn90 Of course, @elimisteve's answer is more concise and generally better, but I still didn't need a for loop, goroutines, or `cmd.Wait()`

Comment: I just checked, io.Copy will block, but running go routines do not block main(). So after your main is finished it will take down your child program and copying goroutines. In this case cmd.Wait is required. (updated the solution to a shorter code)

Comment: @mbert you can throw away errors for quickly testing something with `out, _ := cmd...`

Comment: If you try to open `vim` this way and your terminal output is messed up afterwards: Add a line: `cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin` before run.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

> Now I want to have the stdout of the child program in my terminal
>   window where I started the parent program.

No need to mess with pipes or goroutines, this one is easy.

```
func main() {
    // Replace `ls` (and its arguments) with something more interesting
    cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-l")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Run()
}
```

Comment: In addition, if you want the command to listen for input you can simply set `cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin` thereby making it as if you had literally executed that command from your shell.

Comment: For those looking to redirect to `log` instead of stdout, there is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25191479/616644)

Answer (score 21):

I believe that if you import `io` and `os` and replace this:

```
//fmt.Println(out)
```

with this:

```
go io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)
```

(see documentation [for `io.Copy`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) and [for `os.Stdout`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Variables)), it will do what you want. (Disclaimer: not tested.)

By the way, you'll probably want to capture standard-error as well, by using the same approach as for standard-output, but with `cmd.StderrPipe` and `os.Stderr`.

Comment: @mbert: I had used enough other languages, and had read enough about Go, to have a hunch for what feature would likely exist to do this, and in approximately what form; then I just had to look through the relevant package-docs (found by Googling) to confirm that my hunch was correct, and to find the necessary details. The hardest parts were (1) finding what standard-output is called (`os.Stdout`) and (2) confirming the premise that, if you don't call `cmd.StdoutPipe()` at all, the standard-output goes to `/dev/null` rather than to the parent-process's standard-output.

Answer (score 15):

For those who don't need this in a loop, but would like the command output to echo into the terminal without having `cmd.Wait()` blocking other statements:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error: %s", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    // Replace `ls` (and its arguments) with something more interesting
    cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-l")

    // Create stdout, stderr streams of type io.Reader
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    checkError(err)
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    checkError(err)

    // Start command
    err = cmd.Start()
    checkError(err)

    // Don't let main() exit before our command has finished running
    defer cmd.Wait()  // Doesn't block

    // Non-blockingly echo command output to terminal
    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
    go io.Copy(os.Stderr, stderr)

    // I love Go's trivial concurrency :-D
    fmt.Printf("Do other stuff here! No need to wait.\n\n")
}
```

Comment: Minor fyi: (Obviously) you might miss results of the goroutines started if your "do other stuff here" completes faster than the goroutines. The main() exiting will cause the goroutines to end as well. so you could potentially not end up actually outputing to echo in the terminal if you don't wait for the cmd to finish.