# Golang - Copy Exec output to Log

Tags: go

I would like to redirect the output of a process to `log` in a timely manner.  I can do it if I wait for the process to finish like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("yes", "Go is awesome") // Prints "Go is awesome", forever 
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
log.Printf("%s", out)
```

However, if the process takes a long time or doesn't finish this is less useful.  I know I can write to stdout in real time like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("yes")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()
```

This doesn't really help me though, because I am writing a service that isn't writing to a terminal.  I'm looking for something that will let me do something like:

```
cmd := exec.Command("yes")
cmd.Stdout = log.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = log.Stdout
cmd.Run()
```

`log` doesn't give direct access to its writer so this is not possible.  Surely I'm not the only with this problem, how is this typically done?

Comment: This is caused by buffering in the command you are running. You might find the answers to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) useful.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood While that is indeed a good question for explaining buffering, I'm fairly sure this is not a buffering problem.  CombinedOutput() waits for the program to finish and returns the output and cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout does not exhibit the problem but writes to an undesired output.  Thanks for the comment though...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should use a [pipe](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdoutPipe) here, for example:

```
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    return 0, err
}

// start the command after having set up the pipe
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    return 0, err
}

// read command's stdout line by line
in := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

for in.Scan() {
    log.Printf(in.Text()) // write each line to your log, or anything you need
}
if err := in.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("error: %s", err)
}
```

I have only handled `Stdout` here, but it is possible to handle `Stderr` at the same time, for example by using a goroutine.

Comment: Couple of suggestions: Get the StderrPipe() then do `multi := io.MultiReader(stdout, stderr)`. Then do `in := bufio.NewScanner(multi)`.  This allows a single scanner and no goroutine which I think is quite nice. I think `scanner.Err()` should be `in.Err()`.  I took out the `return 0, err` and just made it `return err`.  Great answer, thanks!

Comment: When I use this solution combined with the solution provided by @RickSmith the output is in reverse order (last line first, first line last). I think the for loop might need modified?

Comment: @Arcite there is no reason why a pipe might reverse the order of lines.This would mean that the program being piped runs backwards in time, which is pretty unlikely given our current knowledge in time travel technologies. More seriously, please ask a new question with your exact reproducible issue.

Answer (score 5):

Both `exec.Command` and `log.Logger` are based on an `io.Writer`. You don't have access to those of the second, but you don't need to because either you didn't changed it, and you're using `os.Stderr` or you changed it and you have the `io.Writer` at hand when creating the logger.

So you just have to adapt you second example by using the right `io.Writer`…

**Edit**

After some though on it, I think you may be good to go by just embedding a `log.Logger` into a struct that will implement the `io.Writer` interface…

Example:

```
type LogWriter struct {
    logger *log.Logger
}

func NewLogWriter(l *log.Logger) *LogWriter {
    lw := &LogWriter{}
    lw.logger = l
    return lw
}

func (lw LogWriter) Write (p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    lw.logger.Println(p)
    return len(p), nil
}
```

And then pass it to your `exec.Command` output…

```
cmd := exec.Command(…)
cmd.Stdout = NewLogWriter(log.New(…))
```

You can use it for both standard or error output, or create new object for each one.

**Edit2**

As I'm going to use this trick for one of my next projects, I put it into a package on [github](https://github.com/elwinar/logwriter). Feel free to give feedback, etc.

Comment: Using the logger's Writer directly while using the Logger itself is not a good idea, because a Logger allows access from multiple goroutines without mangling its output, which a pure Writer does not. Also, in contrast to a Writer, a Logger normally decorates the output, which the OP probably desires, for example to have the exact date of the output in the log file.

Comment: @SirDarius: Updated my answer with an idea that popped while reading your comment. What do you think about that ?

Comment: Nice idea too. Encapsulating a logger into a Writer should be part of the standard library imho !

Comment: As it is not and as I'm thinking of using it in my next project (involve commands, happy coincidence), I put it into a package of my own on [github](https://github.com/elwinar/logwriter). Feel free to use it, to give me feedback, etc. I will put it on godoc too when I will have the documentation done. Not that it's hard, thought…