# Getting output from `exec.Cmd` in "real-time"

Tags: go, exec, stdout, buffering

This question is similar to [Golang - Copy Exec output to Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190971/golang-copy-exec-output-to-log) except it is concerned with the buffering of output from `exec` commands.

I have the following test program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "inf_loop.py")
    var out outstream
    cmd.Stdout = out
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(cmd.Wait())
}

type outstream struct{}

func (out outstream) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    fmt.Println(string(p))
    return len(p), nil
}
```

`inf_loop.py`, which the above refers to, simply contains:

```
print "hello"
while True:
    pass
```

The go program hangs when I run it and doesn't output anything, but if I use `os.Stdout` instead of `out` then it outputs "hello" before it hangs. Why is there a discrepancy between the two `io.Writer`s and how can it be fixed?

Some more diagnostic information:

- When the loop is removed from `inf_loop.py` then "hello" is output from both programs, as expected.
- When using `yes` as the program instead of the python script and outputting `len(p)` in `outstream.Write` then there is output, and the output is usually 16384 or 32768. This indicates to me that this is a buffering issue, as I originally anticipated, but I still don't understand why the `outstream` structure is being blocked by buffering but `os.Stdout` isn't. One possibility is that the behaviour is the result of the way that `exec` passes the `io.Writer` directly to `os.StartProcess` if it is an `os.File` (see [source](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go#L209) for details), otherwise it creates an `os.Pipe()` between the process and the `io.Writer`, and this pipe may be causing the buffering. However, the operation and possible buffering of `os.Pipe()` is too low-level for me to investigate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python buffers stdout by default. Try this program:

```
import sys
print "hello"
sys.stdout.flush()
while True:
    pass
```

or run Python with unbuffered stdout and stderr:

```
cmd := exec.Command("python", "-u", "foo.py")
```

Note the -u flag.

You see different results when using `cmd.Stout = os.Stdout` because Python uses line buffering when stdout is a terminal.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! Just for future reference, I was curious as to how Python knows that stdout is a terminal in the latter case and found that the general approach is to use [ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl#Unix).

Comment: BTW, Linux (actually GNU coreutils) and FreeBSD (and possibly others) have `stdbuf` which changes the initial buffering of arbitrary commands. Useful for commands that don't have options (like the `-u` shown here or grep's `--line-buffered`) for doing it directly.